# How can I use Procfile for my react app on heroku plateform

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am working with react and I need to upload my project on Heroku platform so I tried to upload on Heroku and got `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` this error and I read about this error so I created a file procfile and added:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 server.js
```

But now it is generated a new issue `Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js` so what can I do to solve this issue??

Comment: Do you have any import statement like `/app/server.js` in your app?

Comment: @Ramesh No! I don`t have an import statement like In reactJs there is App.js root file.

Answer (score 0):

in Procfile

```
web: react-scripts --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 start
```

OR

in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 start",
    "build": "react-scripts --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 build",
}
```